# Use grep to find any lines that have the letter a, e or i followed by the letter o or u

Tags: text-processing, grep

```
grep [aei].*[ou]
```

This command is wrong.

Comment: You need to quote it to make it work. But then the `.*` is useless there.

Comment: Do you mean _immediately_ following, or just somewhere afterwards, on the same line? Do you have example that should match and examples that should not match? In what way does your command not work? Do you have any file in your current directory that matches that globbing pattern, for example, `i.you` or `e.fu`?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `.*` (that is represent for zero or more of any-characters except newline) in between, saying any one of `a`, `e` or `i` characters **immediately** followed by `o` or `u` not anything else between.

and another thing is you need to quote the pattern to avoid shell globbing interpretation.

```
grep '[aei][ou]' infile
```

Comment: Well, it will work though as `.*` it will match zero or more of any-characters.

Comment: @annahri yes, you are right, quoting also should be there, I had quote but didn't add note about that. I edited answer, thanks